# How to catch OPTIONS method call

Tags: javascript, http-options-method

My API is down right now, and my app crashed spectacularly due to the `OPTIONS` call getting a 503. After searching high and low, I've discovered it is very hard to Google "Catch failed options call", et al. without getting a bunch of posts about people asking what the `OPTIONS` call is, or more posts about passing `options` to an API call.

So, how do I capture a failed `OPTIONS` call in my code. Here is a sample snippet from where a call is being made that fails.

```
const userPreferences = yield fetch(url, options).then((response) => response);
const result = yield userPreferences.json();
if (userPreferences.status !== 200) {
  yield put(saveError(result));
} else {
  yield put(savePreferences(result));
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `yield`? Why do you not perform actions within `.then()`?

Comment: I find it easier to read this way inside a generator function.

Comment: What are you trying to determine? Have you tried `mode:"no-cors"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  That's something your browser will do for you when trying to figure out things like CORS.  Only your browser will get the response to that.  It won't pass the results to your code.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :(

Comment: I'm thrilled to see you using generator functions, but I'm not as familiar with them as I'd like to be.  I'm having trouble understanding what happens if the Promise returned by fetch is rejected.